# Postgres Not returning anything. Doesn't timeout. Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm working on a project that used to run on an old machine, which makes me guess I set up postgres incorrectly.  I haven't worked on web in a few years.

Ever since I switched to my new computer I haven't been able to get it running.

I make a call to the database from the server, and instead of timing out it just gets hung up indefinitely.  I don't see any error messages.  Console logs show me what's happening on the server.  It appears that my calls are being sent, but then nothing seems to happen.

Here is my server:

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sessionMiddleware = require('./modules/session-middleware');

const passport = require('./strategies/user.strategy');

// Route includes
const userRouter = require('./routes/user.router');

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Passport Session Configuration //
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

// start up passport sessions
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/* Routes */
app.use('/api/user', userRouter);

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static('build'));

// App Set //
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

/** Listen * */
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

The same issue appears with a Postman request.  No response.  It just gets hung up.

Edit:
Here is the `user.strategy.js` where I am making the calls:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const encryptLib = require('../modules/encryption');
const pool = require('../modules/pool');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE id = $1', [id]).then((result) => {
    // Handle Errors
    const user = result && result.rows && result.rows[0];

    if (user) {
      // user found
      delete user.password; // remove password so it doesn't get sent
      // done takes an error (null in this case) and a user
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      // user not found
      // done takes an error (null in this case) and a user (also null in this case)
      // this will result in the server returning a 401 status code
      done(null, null);
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error with query during deserializing user ', error);
    // done takes an error (we have one) and a user (null in this case)
    // this will result in the server returning a 500 status code
    done(error, null);
  });
});

// Does actual work of logging in
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE username = $1', [username])
      .then((result) => {
        const user = result && result.rows && result.rows[0];
        if (user && encryptLib.comparePassword(password, user.password)) {
          // All good! Passwords match!
          // done takes an error (null in this case) and a user
          done(null, user);
        } else {
          // Not good! Username and password do not match.
          // done takes an error (null in this case) and a user (also null in this case)
          // this will result in the server returning a 401 status code
          done(null, null);
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error with query for user ', error);
        // done takes an error (we have one) and a user (null in this case)
        // this will result in the server returning a 500 status code
        done(error, null);
      });
  }));

module.exports = passport;
```

Edit 2: Here is the pool.js (notes are from my old instructor, if helpful):

```
const pg = require('pg');
const url = require('url');

let config = {};

if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  // Heroku gives a url, not a connection object
  // https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool
  const params = url.parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
  console.log("pool.js process.env.DATABASE_URL: " + process.env.DATABASE_URL);
  const auth = params.auth.split(':');
  console.log("pool.js params: " + params + ", auth: " + " auth: " + auth);
  config = {
    user: auth[0],
    password: auth[1],
    host: params.hostname,
    port: params.port,
    database: params.pathname.split('/')[1],
    ssl: true, // heroku requires ssl to be true
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
  };
} else {
  config = {
    host: 'localhost', // Server hosting the postgres database
    port: 5432, // env var: PGPORT
    database: 'name_of_db', // CHANGE THIS LINE! env var: PGDATABASE, this is likely the one thing you need to change to get up and running
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
  };
}

// this creates the pool that will be shared by all other modules
const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

// the pool with emit an error on behalf of any idle clients
// it contains if a backend error or network partition happens
pool.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Unexpected error on idle client', err);
  process.exit(-1);
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Edits 3 & 4: After some time I eventually get this client side error:
`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/user/register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000. See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).`

Edit 5: Questions I've received on other forums

> are you able to connect to Postgres from outside your node app to
> ensure it’s running on the correct host + port?

I can send a request to the endpoint in Postman, but it seems that it will not time out. I seemingly get hung up. No error message returned.
I have console logs in the server and know that I am at least sending the calls.
I just seem to get no response. Not even a 500.

> Hi, are you starting the server with 'npm run server' in the terminal?
> And then starting the application with 'npm run client'?

Yep. Both of those appear to be working. The client is appearing on the DOM.  I can fill out the forms on the frontend. That all appears to be working.
When I run the server I'm getting the log that the server is listening on 5000.  Console logs appear in the server so I know that information is being received.
The bottleneck appears to be with sending to the Database.

Comment: Are you returning a response from your handler? None of your code shows any relevance to calls to Postgres or the console logs you mention

Comment: @AdamJenkins Updated original post

Comment: Any chance this is your problem? https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2069#issuecomment-619456031

Comment: @AdamJenkins I don't think so?  My version of node is 16.0.0, PostgreSQL@14, and my pg version in my package.json is "^7.18.2".  Everything appears to be up to date.

Comment: Added the pool.js if that's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I either hadn't created the database, or I created it and then deleted it.

Once I switched to an existing database everything worked.

To find an existing server I used the command:
`psql -l`

Then I connected to one of those servers on a GUI (I'm using Postico - not that it matters).

In my `pool.js` I changed the database name to the same existing server:

```
if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  const params = url.parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
  console.log("pool.js process.env.DATABASE_URL: " + process.env.DATABASE_URL);
  const auth = params.auth.split(':');
  console.log("pool.js params: " + params + ", auth: " + " auth: " + auth);
  config = {
    user: auth[0],
    password: auth[1],
    host: params.hostname,
    port: params.port,
    database: params.pathname.split('/')[1],
    ssl: true, // heroku requires ssl to be true
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
  };
} else {
  config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'name_of_db', <<<< I CHANGED THIS TO MATCH THE EXISTING DATABASE
    max: 10, 
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, 
  };
}
```

NOTE: I *did* update pg to its most recent version (8.10.0) before trying this, which may have had something to do with it working as well.

`npm install pg@8.10.0`

---

Once I was connected to an actual database, I was able to create a new database in Postico (the GUI I'm using).